# Converting a CBitmap to HICON and using it on a status bar

Tags: c++, mfc, statusbar

I found this [link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?441251-CBitmap-to-HICON-or-HICON-from-HBITMAP) that shows you how to convert a `CBitmap` into a `HICON`:

```
HICON HICONFromCBitmap(CBitmap& bitmap)
{
   BITMAP bmp;
   bitmap.GetBitmap(&bmp);

   HBITMAP hbmMask = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(::GetDC(NULL), 
                                              bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight);

   ICONINFO ii = {0};
   ii.fIcon    = TRUE;
   ii.hbmColor = bitmap;
   ii.hbmMask  = hbmMask;

   HICON hIcon = ::CreateIconIndirect(&ii);
   ::DeleteObject(hbmMask);

   return hIcon;
}
```

So I have tried this in my application:

```
HICON hIcon = HICONFromCBitmap(m_mapMenuBitmap[5]);
VERIFY(hIcon);
m_StatusBar.GetStatusBarCtrl().SetIcon(paneProgressOrZoomFactor, hIcon);
```

It works:

[image: Status Bar]

Does `hIcon` need to be alive for the duration of my window? And do I have to free it?

For your clarification, my `m_mapMeniBitmaps` is a map of `CBitmap` objects and they **do remain alive**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does hIcon need to be alive for the duration of my window? And do I have to free it?*

Yes and yes! From the [documentation for `CreateIconIndirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createiconindirect) (bolding mine):

> When you are **finished using the icon**, destroy it using the
>   DestroyIcon function.

*My `m_mapMenuBitmaps` is a map of `CBitmap` objects and they do remain alive.*

You *can* free those `CBitmap` objects once you've created the icon(s) but, as you correctly note, they remain 'alive', so you should *always* 'kill' them when you no longer need them. From the same M/S document:

> The system **copies** the bitmaps in the ICONINFO structure before
>   creating the icon or cursor.
>   ...
>   The application must continue to manage the original bitmaps and
>   delete them when they are no longer necessary.

Comment: I simplified your answer then just to the the specifics of my question as it was about `HICON`. OK?

Comment: That's fine.  I seem to be in an uncharacteristically nice mood today, so take advantage while you can. ‎

Comment: I suppose it might be worth re-including part of your stement where you indicate it is safe to delete a `CBitmap` if you so desire... Worth staying me reckons!